# Storage of Date/Datetime/Time/Timestamp in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, types, google-bigquery, relational-database

From the [`Bigquery docs`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#data), the date, datetime, time, and timestamp field all consume `8 bytes` in storage:

```
DATE    8 bytes
DATETIME    8 bytes
TIME    8 bytes
TIMESTAMP   8 bytes
```

Why is this so, given that the `DATE` could be stored in less than that?

```
Name    Range
DATE    0001-01-01 to 9999-12-31.
```

And compared against `DATETIME` which would require more:

```
Name    Range
DATETIME    0001-01-01 00:00:00 to 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999
```

Are all four of these types stored the same way in the storage layer, or why is it that all four of these types are all 8 bytes?

Comment: The documentation you are citing talks about sizes used for **billing**, not about how data is encoded at storage layer.

Comment: Why does it matter? We're long past the days of holding years as 2 digits to save storage.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the implementation at the storage layer is not available within the documentation, the only documentation available is the one you mentioned [pricing-data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#data) & [data-types](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#date_type) where you can find how BigQuery performs the data size calculation for billing purpose and the data type ranges.

However, if this suppose an issue for your specific use-case, you can create a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162685) by providing all the information requested within the form.